# The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, apt

I have the following step in my CircleCi setup to install Google Chrome:

```
  - run:
      name: Install Chrome headless
      working_directory: /
      command: |
        wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
          echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
          apt-get update && \
          apt-get install -y dbus-x11 google-chrome-unstable && \
          rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

It stopped working and return the following error message:

```
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551 Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Reading package lists... Done


Building dependency tree       


Reading state information... Done

The following additional packages will be installed:
  libappindicator3-1 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libindicator3-7
Recommended packages:
  libu2f-udev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus-x11 google-chrome-unstable libappindicator3-1 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libindicator3-7
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
Need to get 60.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 214 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  google-chrome-unstable
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
Exited with code 100
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't understand why Google makes it so difficult (partially impossible) to report bugs. I've found even Account-concerning Bugs last year and they didn't allow me in any form to contact them. So sad.

Comment: Have you tried contacting `linux-packages-keymaster@google.com`?

Comment: I have the exact same GPG error. Maybe Google messed something up signing their latest updates?

Comment: this question has a better title yet I see duplicate over at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551 ... possible solution is to comment out its normal install you show above and manually copy over a previous install of google

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have contacted `linux-packages-keymaster@google.com` now. Let's see if I get any response (I have pretty low confidence though)

Comment: looks like google already fixed the issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=952287

Comment: Really seems like Google fixed it. I just ran an `apt update` and there weren't any more errors.

Comment: Got Chrome working (I think), but am still seeing this problem with google earth.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't. You must wait for Google to renew their keys and for an update.

The important message is:

> The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551 Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority)

It means that the cryptographic signature is invalid. The source of this can be an attack, a misconfiguration, or other kind of technical problem. Forcing your system to update will result in running an unverified version of your web browser, which can expose you to a lot of security troubles.

Comment: It's breaking CI pipelines all over the place. Do you know any way to ignore a repository when running `apt update` ? Our pipeline does not need a more recent version of this repo.

Comment: Apt doesn’t have the possibilité to skip a repository. What about redirecting STDERR to a log file? `apt update 2>/tmp/apt_error.log`

Comment: @DamienClauzel you can bypass the check with `trusted=yes` in your source list. See https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.en.html

i.e. `deb [trusted=yes] http://dl.google....`

Comment: Yes, but this does not skip the repository: instead, it makes it treated as always secured, which is not the same thing at all. With this, you will get an untrusted update (this is Bad) instead of having no update.

Answer (score 9):

It's the same as this question (10 mins of difference): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551

Short explanation: the GPG key on Google side expired, so you (we) have to wait.

Comment: I dont't think so, because they have renewed it in 2017 already, see my gist from back then: https://gist.github.com/YaguraStation/1f707c9c0ebd666ca3e943c7eec8ad0c 

Also an `apt-key list` on an affected machine should show that the keys only expire 2020.

Comment: @YaguraStation GPG keys expire sooner or later, that is the case. You can lookup this problem (already solved, but for future reference) here on google support forum: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4032170?hl=en

Comment: Here you can find the details of the key used previously by Google: https://pgp.key-server.io/pks/lookup?search=0x7721F63BD38B4796&fingerprint=on&op=vindex . The expire date is at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

**Plan 1**

> This is the protection you are getting from these checks. You don't
>   want to update your software right now while something is messed up on
>   Google's end. Wait until they fix it. Don't try to override by
>   reinstalling keys until some official word comes out that a new key is
>   the solution.

**Plan 2**

> Waiting until they fix it may not be an option for all. E.g. this is
>   breaking CI pipelines for us. If you now what you are doing, you might
>   take the risk and disable checks for this repo for now by adding
>   [trusted=yes] to it's configuration: deb [trusted=yes]
>   http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main –

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551/1133345#1133345)

Answer (score 3):

I simply commented out the entry in etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list so I don't see the error anymore.